# "known data" in secure erase

Tags: disk-utility, security

The second level of "secure erase" in disk utility is said to write two passes of random and then "one pass of known data."  There's nothing on my disk worth hiding, but I'm curious: What exactly ***is*** the "known data" and doesn't knowing it make it less of an obstacle to any deep-pocket spies who might want to listen to my old discarded music?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "known data" just means that it is a pattern that is not random, but pre-set. I.e. overwriting the whole disk with zeroes, ones or "HELLO WORLD" or anything like that.

Knowing the pattern doesn't make it any less of an obstacle for spies to.

Note that in any case, this type of secure erase is only suitable for magnetic storage such as old-fashioned hard disk drives, or even more old-fashioned floppy disk drives. It is not the proper way to securely erase flash storage such as modern SSDs.

Comment: I figured the "secure erase" would be kind of silly for an SSD.  I wonder whether Disk Utility would say so if I were to try it (which I can't because all of my externals are spinners).

Comment: The Security Options button is not there if you try to Erase an SSD. <me carefully pressing 'Cancel' twice> https://i.stack.imgur.com/hT64G.png vs https://i.stack.imgur.com/0MZjm.png